# Distribution of outgoing calls

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I know that stream of independent events obeys Poisson distribution (so summary stream of calls that achieved Phone Station (PBX) will obey Poisson distribution).

But I don't think separate streams from separate subscriber obey this distribution (because events are not independent, they made by one person)

So, my question: what distribution can I use to simulate one person's call stream, that SUM of many streams will be Poisson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume one person can make a call, in probability $p$, or not to make a call, with probability $q=1-p$, the total number of calls made by many users is binomial, and by the [Poisson limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem) it is approximately Poisson distributed.